# Using SSL with MySource Matrix

Tags: https

I have a MySource Matrix web server running on Centos 5.4/Apache 2.2.3.

The MySource Matrix is configured with a few hostnames, notably 10.1.1.1 (the servers ip) and www.mysite.com (the name to access the site)

It all works fine with HTTP, but we just enabled HTTPS and the MySource is using http//10.1.1.1/ as the basis for all links/stylesheets etc, rather than https://www.mysite.com.

How do we tell MySourceMatrix that https://www.mysite.com is a valid URL to have used, so it doesn't rewrite all URLS to the default http//10.1.1.1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - as well as enabling HTTPS for the site it needs to be enabled for the design folder.